# How to deploy iOS app to a iPhone using Delphi Seattle without Apple developer account?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, delphi, provisioning-profile

XCode 7 no longer needs an Apple developer account to deploy apps to iPhone. On Delphi, to deploy apps we must use the provisioning configurations to deploy it. This configuration is only available to an Apple developer member.

With this new possibility, someone knows how to make delphi deploy without this configuration?

Comment: I haven't used Delphi 10 Seattle yet, but it's likely that they have not made this possible yet. What's so wrong about using an Apple developer account?

Comment: Nothing "wrong", I just need to pay $99 for each account and I don`t have one, and it`s a good opportunity to test iOs apps.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that part since I'm not the one who paid for it.

Comment: Fortunately it`ll be not necessary anymore...

Comment: That's not completely true @SaCi, there's a difference between those apps sent to phone with and without an apple approved signature even while testing. Checkout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Create an iOS application in XCode 7 with the bundle identifier you want to use in your Delphi project
2. Deploy the XCode application to your device. XCode will install the certificates and profiles (Project -> Run)
3. Set CFBundleIdentifier in the Delphi project options to the chosen bundle identifier.
4. Select the Development Configuration in the Delphi project manager
5. Press F9 to deploy your application

I've tested this with Delphi 10 Seattle and it works.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, and I get this. [PAClient Error] Error: E0264 Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/codesign" --deep -s "iPhone Developer: Rodrigo Farias Rezino (3E2ZX36RE2)" -f "/Users/rodrigofariasrezino/PAServer/scratch-dir/rfrezino-rfrezio/RfR.Programa.app"' (Error 1), [PAClient Error] Error: E0264 iPhone Developer: Rodrigo Farias Rezino (3E2ZX36RE2): ambiguous (matches "iPhone Developer: Rodrigo Farias Rezino (3E2ZX36RE2)" and "iPhone Developer: Rodrigo Farias Rezino (3E2ZX36RE2)" in /Users/rodrigofariasrezino/Library/Keychains/login.keychain). Didn't you get it ?

Comment: No, I didn't get that. But I've seen that before. Open the ´keychain´ application in OSX and select the `My Certificates`category. Most likely you have two certificates with the same name. One of them needs to be removed. Have fun figuring out which one :-)

Comment: Muchhhhh thanks Sebastian Z! It worked! The problem was once I have an account and it expired, i removed the old certification and now everything is working!

Comment: I'll assume this works in all versions of Firemonkey?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure that it works with any Delphi versions that is compatible with XCode 7. The steps will obviously be a little bit different for Delphi versions that can't retrieve the certificates automatically.

Comment: I have Seattle as well, but I keep getting a F2588 Linker Errorcode: 1 when I try this.

Comment: Ah. Never mind, it's a Parallels Problem. Following this https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109069 now everything works as exepected.