# How do you store and play media files in a Delphi FireMonkey iOS application?

Tags: ios, delphi, media-player, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I wrote a FireMonkey application (Delphi 10.1 Berlin) which includes sound, mp3's played via TMediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'aSound.mp3'); 
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

Works great on Windows. For a mobile version of the app, I got help figuring out where to put the sound files from [this link](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-tutorials/151-ui/927-deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android):

> Use the Project | Deployment menu item and select the Android and the
>   iOS Device platforms and for each one click the "Add Files" button in
>   the local toolbar to select the bitmap file to deploy with the app and
>   set the Remote Path column value for each platform.
>
> ```
> For Android, set the Remote Path to .\assets\internal
> For iOS, set the Remote Path to StartUp\Documents
> ```

Adding the files to `\assets\internal` for Android deployment also works fine--sounds play as expected.

I loaded the app onto an ios device with help from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663131/how-to-deploy-ios-app-to-a-iphone-using-delphi-seattle-without-apple-developer-a#32665102). The app runs fine--except there's no sound. Other apps still make sound, so I know it's not the iPad that's the issue. I tried setting the iOS sound file deployment path to `Startup\Documents\` and `StartUp\Documents` (which Delphi just saved as `Startup\Documents.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "which Delphi just saved as Startup\Documents". How do you mean? If you enter it with a capital U, that is what it should stay as (and is also the correct path).

Comment: @DaveNottage I ultimately deleted the files, and then re-added them to StartUp\Documents. My ios device shows their path as `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/756733A2-1702-424E-9D90-A6AC453EC0C6/Documents/aSound.mp3`

Comment: Does that mean it's all good now?

Comment: Sadly, no ... It must be something about TMediaPlayer on iOS, I guess.

Comment: That's it; it supports only .caf files:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer

Comment: I _just_ saw the same point made in the Berlin documentation: [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer] ... I'll see if I can figure out how to convert the file format and try it. However, the same documentation says MediaPlayer doesn't play mp3 files on Windows or Android--and it's playing the mp3 format just fine for me on those OS's.

Comment: Converting mp3 to caf didn't help.

Comment: Looking at the source for FMX.Media.iOS.pas, it implies (in the initialization section) that .wav, .caf, .m4a and .mp3 files are supported. I'll do a bit of digging, but you should use FileExists (or TFile.Exists) to make sure that the path to the file is correct

Answer (score 0):

iOS is case sensitive on the remote path, you wrote `Startup\Documents\` it must be `StartUp\Documents\`

Also always include a check to make sure the file is there with `FileExists` that way if the file is not found your App can handle it accordingly.